# Spark-Yarn Wrong FS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark job that work, but when I try to execute it over Yarn, there is an exception that I don't know how to solve it ore where I need to make the update. Error is the following:

```
017-11-30 10:28:49,952 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying hdfs://servername1.domain.net:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20171123121217/spark2/spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.cloudera1.jar
2017-11-30 10:28:49,972 [main] INFO  org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client  - Deleted staging directory hdfs://servername1:8020/user/pe3016/.sparkStaging/application_1511521415490_0216
2017-11-30 10:28:49,974 [main] ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext  - Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://servername.domain.net:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20171123121217/spark2/spark-yarn_2.11-2.2.0.cloudera1.jar, expected: hdfs://servername:8020
```

I'm using cloudera 5.12.1

Comment: Check core-site.xml for fs.default.name property. What value does it have?